# iOS / Swift - Can't get Keyboard appearance to move view after the first time it is used

Tags: ios, swift

I have spent nearly a day trying lots of different methods from various articles and tutorials but I have not been able to get a fully working solution to my problem. (And it is driving me slightly insane)

When a text field is edited, the keyboard pops up and the view moves up with the keyboard. This only happens however the first time a textfield is edited after the app is restarted. The keyboard goes away with the view anywhere else is pressed on the view.
The next time a text field is edited however the keyboard moves up but the view doesn't and the textfield is under the keyboard.

Here is my current code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))

        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }


    func dismissKeyboard() {

        view.endEditing(true)
    }


    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
                self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you tried putting every UI elements in one view and change that view's constraints? Changing view controller's view is not good practice.

Comment: @Emre Hi, I have added a subview and put everything in that then referenced that in the code but the same thing happens, the view moves the first time you edit a text box but the second textbox makes the view return to normal, with textfields under the keyboard.

Comment: I guess you are creating your view with Storyboard and AutoLayout. Just create a IBOutlet of a bottom of constraint container view and change it in your methods, not frame.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. The problem is 'keyboardSize.height' is 0 after the first time. Why? A hack would be to store the height the first time. Not helpful, but I think in 'keyboardWillHide' you don't need the keyboardSize... you can just set origin.y to 0. Still will have the same issue though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use IQKeyboardManagerSwift cocoa pod in your project it will solve your problem
You can find library here : https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

and use it according to given instructions.

Thanx!

Comment: Yeah I tried that aswell but it squashed my view so the textfields were super tiny. I went through the various instructions on their site aswell but none of them produced the right result

Comment: You try this after remove UITapGestureRecognizer and NotificationsCenters??

Comment: Yes I commented all of these out but the view gets squashed and when I change it to a scrollView the view doesnt move at all. Also tried setting the bottom layer to the IQ constraint but I cant get that to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Change UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey to UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey. I've just tested it and it works.